# useSWR doesn't return the response as {data,error} when an error occurs

Tags: next.js, error-handling, swr, use-swr

I have a simple use case where I'm fetching data from an api based on the value of the router.query in NEXT JS.

```
const { data, error } = useSWR(() => {
  if (router.query.sort === "shortest")
    return `http://localhost:1337/api/playlists/${options?.value}?sortBy=duration`;

  if (router.query.sort === "longest")
    return `http://localhost:1337/api/playlists/${options?.value}?sortBy=duration&order=desc`;

  if (router.query.sort === "oldest")
    return `http://localhost:1337/api/playlists/${options?.value}?sortBy=id`;

  return `http://localhost:1337/api/playlists/${options?.value}?sortBy=id&order=desc`;
});
```

[useswr doesn't return the response in the same format as the docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzKPM.png)

When an error occurs in any one of the api endpoints, instead of reading directly the error as listed above, I found that it's returned undefined but instead another {data,error} is nested inside the data that is first returned which is different from what the docs describes. Hopefully my description is clear enough. Please clarify if I'm doing anything wrong here